# How to send json response in redirect url for jquery file upload

Tags: json, redirect, cgi, jquery-file-upload

I am using blueimp file upload and on server side i am using cgi script.I am able to upload the file and getting valid json data.Now what i want is to sent this json data to the redirect url so i can do further procession on the redirect page.

My js code in jsp page is as follows:-

```
$(function () {
    //alert(window.location.hostname);
    'use strict';
    var urlTemp = '<%=actionStr%>';
    var successurl = '<%=successURL%>';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
            {
                url: urlTemp,
                sequentialUploads: true,
                redirect: successurl,
                type: 'POST'
            }
        );
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadstop', 
            function (e, data) {
                data.formdata = data.result;
                alert(data);
                alert(data.formdata); //getting undefined
                window.location.href = successurl;

            }
    );
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option','url');
});
```

in fileuploadstop event i am getting data.result as 'undefined'.

Comment: try 'fileuploaddone', you will see the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
  var results = data.result;
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i pass this data with redirected url ?

Comment: try this:sorry I am not able to format here: $(function() {
  /* activate the plugin */
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({submit: function (e, data) {
        
     var $this = $(this);
     debugger;
        $.getJSON('/rest/file/url?' + new Date().getTime(), function (result) {
         data.url = result.url;
            $this.fileupload('send', data);
        });
        return false;
    }
 });

 
});

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to pass data with redirect URL

```
   $(function() {
 /* activate the plugin */ 
$('#fileupload').fileupload({submit: function (e, data) {
 var $this = $(this);
 $.getJSON('/rest/file/url?' + new Date().getTime(), function (result) { data.url = result.url; 
$this.fileupload('send', data); 
}); return false;
 } 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        replaceFileInput: false,
        url:"/photo",
        method: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        paramName: 'photo[photo]',
        recalculateProgress: false,
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                    progress + '%'
            );
        },
        done: function(e, data) {
            console.log(data.result);
        }
    });
});
```

put you code into `done` function